# How can I disable scrolling to certain anchors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've added anchor scrolling to my website, however because I've used anchors for elements in my carousel, every time I click on the carousel indicators, the page scrolls down a bit.

How can I disable those anchors from being included? This is my jquery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){$('a[href^="#"]').on("click",function(a){a.preventDefault();
                                                                      
var b=this.hash,c=$(b);
                                                                      
$("html,body").stop().animate({scrollTop:c.offset().top},900,"swing",function(){window.location.hash=b})})});
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

remove them from the selection with not.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').not(".YourCarousel a").on("click", ...
```